# Text visualization using scattertext for multiple category

Tags: python, nlp, data-visualization, spacy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                 new                                            categoryname
0    screwed screwed screwed screwed screwed screwe...          agr
1           family family family family family family           opn
2    partying partying partying partying partying p...          agr
3                       love love love love love love           neu
```

I want to visualize this dataframe using `scattertext`. However, the examples I see in the internet all are binary (democrat vs republic or positive vs negative).

I was wondering is there any way we can visualize a multiple class dataset like above?

I have tried this:

```
corpus = st.CorpusFromParsedDocuments(df, category_col='categoryname', parsed_col='new').build()
html = st.produce_scattertext_explorer(corpus,
                                       category='categoryname',
                                       category_name='categoryname',
                                       not_category_name='new',
                                       width_in_pixels=1000,
                                       minimum_term_frequency=5,
                                       transform=st.Scalers.scale,
                                       metadata=df['new'])
```

But it raises an error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'sents'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I am not sure this is the correct way of doing this. Because in the examples, they provide name of the category (democrat, non-democrat) But I have multiple categories.

Any idea how to fix this?
I want `a visualization tool` that shows the text (except word cloud).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you either create a series of one-vs-rest Scattertext plots comparing each category to all others, and/or make a set of one-vs-one comparing each category to each other category separately.

Then, build HTML scaffolding around the set of plots to enable users to select the categories they'd want to compare.

You can see an example of it in https://github.com/JasonKessler/acl17-handbook/blob/master/scattertext-analysis/Scattertext-Analysis.ipynb

As to why the code its self isn't working, there look to be a number of errors. The column "new" should be parsed spaCy documents, and the category parameter to produce_scattertext_explorer should have a value that's in the "categoryname" column, such as "agr".  All other categories in the data frame will be treated as a single negative category.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Actually I need to represent all categories in one shot. What I mean is that I dont want user to select each category seperately and then compare in this way. Do you have any recommendation  I can plot them in one figure?